# Ruby Error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby

I am run this code but I am getting an error.

code here :-

```
class Text
    def post(success, error)
        if authenticate?(@user, @password)
            success.call
        else
            erro.call
        end
    end
end
text = Text.new('Ruby Bits!')
success = ->{ puts "Sent!"}
error = ->{ raise 'Auth error'}
text.post(success,error)
```

Please tell us. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Since `post` method definition has two parameters, you'd need to pass two arguments to `post` like so: `test.post(success, error)`

Comment: I am try. It does not remove this error. Show same error

Comment: You are passing the arg "Ruby Bits!" to the initializer of `Text`, but it doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: @harleenkaur: try to initialize a method with one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at which line number the ArgumentError is raised from (in your case, line 25).

You are passing one argument to the Text#initialize, but have not defined a version of initialize that takes one argument.

Try this instead (calling the default, zero argument Text constructor):

```
class Text
    def post(success, error)
        if authenticate?(@user, @password)
            success.call
        else
            error.call
        end
    end
end
text = Text.new
success = ->{ puts "Sent!"}
error = ->{ raise 'Auth error'}
text.post(success, error)
```

Or define initialize with one argument:

```
class Text
    def initialize(your_meaningful_argument)
         # do stuff
    end

    def post(success, error)
        if authenticate?(@user, @password)
            success.call
        else
            error.call
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: show error :- `post': undefined method `authenticate?' for #<test:0x0055afb6a0ada0> (NoMethodError)
 from level-1.rb:30:in `<main>'

Comment: Yes, now you're trying to call the instance method authenticate? on your instance of the Text class, but you have not defined that method.

Comment: You must define it:

class Text
    def authenticate?
       # do stuff
    end
end
```

Comment: There's still the problem here of `sucess` and `error` not being in the right context. Those should probably be supplied to the constructor and captured as instance variables.